# Generate PNG file with pre-known CRC

Tags: png, digital-signature, crc

Is it possible to create a PNG file with a predefined CRC? (kind of a programming challenge..)
I have a python script to generate hex codes with the target CRC, but I'm not sure how to make a valid PNG out of it.

BTW - it may be that I'm talking nonsense, but it sounds possible on theory (right?)

Comment: A single PNG contains lots of CRCs – one per chunk. Which one(s) do you want to spoof? Or do you mean a full file CRC, like a SHA-1 checksum?

Comment: @RadLexus Although SHA-1 can certainly act as a checksum, it's not a **cyclic** redundancy check. But a good question indeed, Rotem, we need to understand exactly which checksum you want to spoof for us to answer the question. CRC16, CRC32 and over what data?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm actually not sure. I just know that the image should have a specific XMODEM-CRC. I thought that by saying "XMODEM-CRC" the meaning is the whole file's CRC, am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spoof.c](https://github.com/madler/spoof) to do that, either at the level of a PNG chunk or at the level of the entire file. (Note that a PNG file does not contain a CRC of the whole thing, only CRCs of the chunks.)